# Undefined variable. Dentro de un método que pertenece a un clase

Tags: php, controller, class, undefined

Tengo una aplicación PHP escrita sin ningún framework.
Tiene redirección con .htaccess para hacer mi propio sistema de rutas.
El error lo obtengo cuando quiero imprimir una variable en una vista, esta variable está definida en el controlador.

El index.php llama al controlador, el controlador llama a la clase Ruta y la clase Ruta llama a la vista.

index > controlador > ruta > vista

**index.php**

```
<?php

$uri = $server['REQUEST_URI'];
require "{$root}/controladores/Rutas.php";

if ( in_array($uri, ['/']) ) {
    require "{$root}/controladores/InicioControlador.php";
} elseif ( in_array($uri, ['/productos']) ) {
    require "{$root}/controladores/ProductosControlador.php";
}
```

**Controlador Productos**

```
<?php

require "Productos.php";
$Productos = new Productos();
$productos = $Productos->get();

$ruta = new Ruta('ProductosVista.php', ['titulo'=>'Otros Productos', 'post' => $_POST, 'server' => $server]);
```

**Ruta Class**

```
<?php
    
    class Ruta {
    
        private $ruta;
        private $post;
    
        public function __construct (string $ruta, array $post=[]) {
            global $root, $rootHTML;
            $this->ruta = $ruta;
            $this->post = $post;
            $POST = $post;
            require "{$root}/vistas/{$ruta}";
        }
    }
```

**Vista HTML**

```
<?php
    # head
    require "head.php";

    # Mostrar variable
    echo $productos; // Error: no definida a pesar que está definida antes en el controlador

    # fin body
    require "fin-body.php";
?>
```

Por los momentos, para que funcione estoy definiendo la variable dentro de la vista pero eso no está bien. Necesito definir la variable en el controlador y poder acceder a ella desde la vista.

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: La variable `$productos` está definida en el controlador, pero no está visible en `Ruta`. Deberías enviarla como parámetro al constructor o recurrir a la **mala práctica** de agregarla con `global $productos;`

Comment: Ojo que cuando creas el objeto y lo instancias inicia con mayúscula y después cuando accedes al método es con minúscula, deben estar escritos igual

Comment: Estás obrando al revés, deberías invocar la vista desde el controlador (o desde `index,php`, que sería realmente el controlador), pasándole `$productos`  para que lo muestre.

Comment: Gracias, pasaré la variable como parámetro. Lo malo será que no la puedo llamar $productos, sino $MISVARIABLES["productos"]. Saben como hacer lo primero?